# PHP Encryption and decryption is not working when using in $_GET

Tags: php, mysql, encryption, base64, md5

I'm using the following code

```
function encryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qEncoded  = base64_encode( mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), $q, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ) );
    return( $qEncoded );
}

function decryptIt( $q ) {
    $cryptKey  = 'qJB0rGtIn5UB1xG03efyCp';
    $qDecoded  = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ), base64_decode( $q ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
    return( $qDecoded );
}
```

It works fine if i store the value in $_session but if try and encrypt my data in $_GET sometimes it works sometimes it doesn't, let me explain with the code below

```
if(isset($_GET['edit']))
{
    $user_id  = decryptIt($_GET['edit']);
    $errors[] = $user_id;
        if(is_numeric($user_id))
        {
            //set id's to sessions 
            $session->setValues(md5('agent_user'),    encryptIt($get_user->id));
            $session->setValues(md5('agent_person'),  encryptIt($get_person->id));
            $session->setValues(md5('agent_link'),   encryptIt($per_add_lnk->id));
            $session->setValues(md5('agent_address'), encryptIt($get_address->id));

    }else{
        $errors[] = "Errors in the id";
        //redirect to page
    }
}
```

The `$errors[]` prints the following instead **(it should really be a number)**

`����3&-��*"(��@�S]���{]��^�`

That `$user_id = decryptIt($_GET['edit']);` does not work the way i want it to work dont know what is the reason

BTW all my ID's are int(11) auto-increment and this is how i am encrypting:

```
<a href="adduser.php?edit=<?php echo encryptIt($user->id); ?>" class="btn btn-xs blue">
```

output : `adduser.php?edit=jY3e+uLSN8+yhGzLxQX5woA2j53xnBvyYzfr+9tKlYQ=`

Don't what I'm doing wrong and where.

Any idea? please help.

Comment: Can you give an example to an ID? (an example to what you are sending in 'edit')

Comment: @matan7890 integer values mysql auto increment id's only int

Comment: If you're using MD5 as part of your cryptography, you're probably doing it wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to url encode your output

```
<a href="adduser.php?edit=<?php echo urlencode(encryptIt($user->id)); ?>" class="btn btn-xs blue">
```

Charters like `+`, `=` generated by base64 encoding has special meaning in urls.

Comment: +1 To elaborate the `+` in the GET string is being changed to a space character.

Comment: great @Musa... got it working :) i'll accept it in next 20 minutes cant do this before that